# How to add a Separator line to a UITableViewCell (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiedgeinsets

I have custom cells in a `UITableView` and by default they are separated by a separator line. How do I go about adding a second separator line? I'm trying to add one between a `UIImage` and a Text label.

I've been using `UIEdgeInsets` but can't seem to figure it out. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add another separator line. But you can use 1 pixel wide view to simulate it.